# How to generate three 3D unit vectors so that the dot product between each pair is equal to some prespecified value?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm looking to generate three random unit vectors, $x$, $y$, $z \in \mathbb{R}^3$, s.t. $x \cdot y = x \cdot z = y \cdot z = \cos(a)$.

So far, what I've tried is to first start with an orthonormal basis consisting of $x$, $y_0$, and $z_0$ by using the Gram-Schmidt process on three randomly generated vectors. Then, by rotating $y_0$ by $\pm (\frac{\pi}{2} - a)$ with respect to $z_0$ (depending on the direction of $z_0$), I obtained a vector $y$ such that $x \cdot y = \cos(a)$. The last part is to generate a vector $z$ such that $\| z \|^2 = 1$ and $z \cdot x = z \cdot y = \cos(a)$, but here is where I get stuck. Any suggestions? The solution doesn't need to involve rotations as long as $x$, $y$, and $z$ are unit vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

In general, it would be nice to be able to generate $x$, $y$, and $z$ s.t. $x \cdot y = \cos(a)$, $x \cdot z = \cos(b)$, and $y \cdot z = \cos(c)$ for any three real numbers $a$, $b$, and $c$.

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I would pick $u=(1,0,0)$, $v=(\cos a,\sin a,0)$, and $w=(\cos a,w_2,w_3)$, and solve for $\|w\|=1,v\cdot w=\cos a$. Then any $x,y,z$ can be obtained by a random orthogonal transformation of $u,v,w$.

Comment: @Rahul In that case, $w_2 = \frac{\cos(a) - \cos^2(a)}{\sin(a)}$ and $w_3 = \sqrt{1 - \cos^2(a) - w_2^2}$, which may result in having a negative number inside of the squared root for some values of $a$.

Comment: Which values? Is it values greater than $2\pi/3$...? :)

Comment: Lol thank you for the help